# How Do I Turn A Regular Text Variable Into A Variable With HTML (JavaScript) Code?

Tags: javascript, html

Regular Text Variable shows
about:blank

Variable With HTML (I'm Trying To Make Link):
about:blank

My Code So Far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>URLhive</title>
 <script>
  function addItem() {
   var newItem = document.createElement("div");
   newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value;
   newItem.onclick = removeItem;
   document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
  }
  function removeItem() {
   document.getElementById("list").removeChild(this);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
 </div>
 <div class="app">
  <input type="text" id="box" value="Enter A Link Or URL"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Add Link Or URL" onclick="addItem();"/>
  <br/>
   <div id="list"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to open the link inserted to be clickable and onclick it redirects to the url

Comment: It looks like you might be wanting `insertAdjacentHTML` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: The example in [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) documentation shows you how

Comment: Using user input to generate HTML from it, and that even without any sanitization, is ideal for cross site scripting attacks. That being said, just replace `newItem.innerHTML =` with `newItem.innerHTML +=`.

Comment: @connexo Seems like OP hasn't visited the site back after you posted an answer. Maybe they will comment or accept after they are back. And you have put efforts to write an answer. if your answer is good, you should not ask for deletion. Future readers may find your answer useful. Who knows! Feel free to edit the title for better SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface: Using user input to generate HTML from it, and that even without any sanitization, is ideal for **cross site scripting** attacks. Do not ever do this in any production code.

Here's how you achieve what I understood you want:

```js
function addItem() {
  const link = document.getElementById("box").value;
  const newItem = document.createElement("a");
  newItem.href = newItem.textContent = link;
  newItem.target = "_blank";
  newItem.onclick = removeItem;
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
}

function removeItem() {
  this.remove();
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box" placeholder="Enter A Link Or URL" />
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Add Link Or URL" onclick="addItem();" />
<br/>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Please note that this code will not open a link when clicked in the snippet. This seems related to some security restrictions within the iframe this code will be run in. In your actual site, it will work.